# exit status 247 for systemd process

Tags: systemd, exit-status

I have a service that I manage with `systemd` ; to be precise, it runs the daemon for
`django-background-tasks` (but I do not think that this is relevant).

Today it died, as follows

```
$ systemctl --user status coldoc_tasks.service
● coldoc_tasks.service - ColDoc tasks server
   Loaded: loaded (/home/coldoc_data/.config/systemd/user/coldoc_tasks.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Wed 2021-02-10 16:45:29 CET; 1h 6min ago
  Process: 103944 ExecStart=/home/coldoc_sw/ColDoc_virtualenv/bin/python3 ${COLDOC_SRC_ROOT}/ColDocDjango/manage.py process_tasks --dev -v 2 (code=exited, status=247)
 Main PID: 103944 (code=exited, status=247)

Feb 10 09:39:55 cr systemd[215]: Started ColDoc tasks server.
Feb 10 16:45:29 cr systemd[215]: coldoc_tasks.service: Main process exited, code=exited, **status=247/n/a**
Feb 10 16:45:29 cr systemd[215]: coldoc_tasks.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

I did look at the man page `systemd.exec` (as suggested in similar questions in S/E)  to no result. Googling around I see that some other people report similar situations, 247 may be related to memory. Can someone point me to the documentation of this exit code 247?

Comment: The [table in the systemd.exec man page](https://freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.exec.html#id-1.21.8) online doesn't list 247 as a systemd-specific exit code. Perhaps that was the exit status from the python manage.py script?

Comment: an exit code could also be a signal; for `bash` according to https://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exitcodes.html if you subtract 128 you would get a signal number; but 247 - 128 = 119 and that is not a signal according to `man 7 signal`

Comment: I also looked into `/usr/include/sysexits.h`

Comment: Let me also mention that in the line `status=247/n/a` the `n/a` part means that systemd itself has no idea of what this code means

Comment: I forgot to mention `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5323159/what-is-code-247-returned-by-django-1-2-4-development-server` that's where they hint that this code 247 is related to memory

Comment: Try adding options `-X faulthandler` to your python command and it will do a traceback if it gets signals `SIGSEGV SIGFPE SIGABRT SIGBUS SIGILL`. It writes to `sys.stderr`, so make sure that isn't `/dev/null`.

Comment: For what it's worth, I got this error with a circular dependency. Django kept trying to make it work but it froze my machine and eventually exited with code 247